# Does the Sound Blaster Live! Value had hardware support for Adlib/OPL3?

Tags: audio, sound-card, creative

As I m buying a computer without an onboard sound card, I m thinking about using my old Creative Sound card from 21 years ago and buying a pcie riser adapter instead of a modern sound card (I m interested in one with hardware fm synthesis support rather than one emulated through pcm and sampling).
**Please note in that case that it s not only about hardware accelaration and is also about sound quality because of not using pcm sound at all.**

I know that by 1995, Creative abonned fm synthesis and started to use a low quality compatible hardware alternative based on cqm synthesis in order to cut down costs in their pci version of Sound Blaster 16 cards. But as processing powered evolved, cost to include it again should have decreased which doesn t means later models like mine don t include it.

I also know Creative provided a tsr in order to let dos programs perform sound synthesis (I lost the driver CD).
**But I fail to understand if it was for emulating everything or just reroute irq for accessing the hardware?**

**Also, if yes does they use fm synth or still use their low quality cqm based alternative?**

Back in 2006, I was too young to pay attention about this in Windows 98se hardware settings and as Windows doesn t support hardware synthesis since Windows Vista and Linux never had support for such things with pci card, this is something I ve no idea on how to figure.

Comment: Sound cards that old may not have drivers compatible with modern 64-bit operating systems. I remember having trouble getting one of those to work on a  Windows 7 machine with 3GB of RAM, let alone a system with 4GB and 64-bit OS, and that was only about 12 years ago. Frankly you are probably better throwing that card in the bin or finding a similar vintage machine and operating system for it.

Comment: @Mokubai that s a differrent matter. For that reason, the plan is to use back my old ms dos 6.21 still supportting DoubleSpace instead of drivespace by directly booting to it. But if it doesn t have the hardware I want, why bother make it working in the first place?

Comment: So it might be worth editing your question and mentioning that it is your intention to use only MSDOS for it which hopefully should work, but I'm not convinced a PCIE to PCI bridge will work in DOS as it might require driver or operating system support as well....

Comment: The bios should emulate everything. This is how I managed to get Windows 98se booting and working on a live usb. Though that was 9 years ago.

Comment: @Mokubai and in your case, Linux never dropped anything terms of compatibility over 25 years. You can still use a Sound Blaster pro with a 5.x kernel.